# iOS: Issues with creating another UIWindow as an overlay (iOS 7 issues?)

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, overlay, uiwindow

I want to create an overlay view above all other views (including the keyboard), and creating another UIWindow seems to be the way to do this. After reading through [the Windows section of the View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/CreatingWindows/CreatingWindows.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH4-SW1) and some other documents online, it seems like I just need to...

- create the window with the screen bounds,
- set its `windowLevel` to `UIWindowLevelStatusBar`,
- set `userInteractionEnabled` to `NO` (so it would ignore touches),
- and make it visible by setting its `hidden` property to `NO` (without making it the key window, so it does not receive non-touch events).

Here's the code in my app delegate:

```
self.overlayWindow = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
self.overlayWindow.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.overlayWindow.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar;
self.overlayWindow.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
self.overlayWindow.rootViewController = [[OverlayViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
self.overlayWindow.hidden = NO;
```

However, I ran into a few issues:

1. `[self.overlayWindow.rootViewController preferredStatusBarStyle]` is setting the status bar text color when I actually want the root view controller of my original window to be doing this.
2. A big issue is that the extra window is somehow messing up my handling of the software keyboard notifications. It seems like I still get the notifications, but my app is responding strangely in some instances. (I won't explain what these strange behaviors are because they are beside the point.) The point is that I shouldn't be getting these strange behaviors at all: I'm just trying to paint an overlay over the app, and the app should behave just as it did before.
3. I would like the rotations from `overlayWindow` to match up to those of my original window, but it is rotating independently. For example, the swipe-to-go-back gesture of UINavigationController locks the interface orientation, but `overlayWindow` is still able to rotate during this.

What should I do to fix this, so I just get a harmless overlay over the app?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the overlay?

Comment: @BrandonRoth I'm trying to put a message in the middle of the screen for 1 second to alert the user that something in the app has changed (e.g., "Message Sent"). (There are also times where I may want the thing in the middle of the screen to stay longer, like to show a progress bar.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've accomplished something very similar with using a window. In my case I didn't use a UIViewController attached to the window, just the needed subviews so it looked correct.  In order to handle the rotation correctly you can listen to the NSNotification

```
UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarOrientationNotification
```

In the method handler you can grab the device orientation as with a call like so

```
UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
```

And then you can use CGAffineTransformMakeRotation to rotate the views inside your window to the correct orientation.  From the looks of the method you would think you would get the notification after the device orientation has animated, however you'll get it before and when you rotate your view with a transform your rotation will be animated along with everything else (this is assuming things are centered, if there not things are more complicated).  SVProgress hud would be an good example to study if you wanted an example https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD

Comment: This solution solved the last two of the three issues I listed (not assigning a root view controller for the overlay window fixed the keyboard handling glitches), but the overlay window takes over controlling the status bar appearance (I'm using view controller-based status bar appearance). It seems like SVProgressHUD had this problem in the past, but it now doesn't because it's not creating its own UIWindow anymore. I wonder if there's a fix for this other than to opt out of view-controller based status bar appearance. (UIAlertView & UIActionSheet do not seem to have this problem.)

Comment: I haven't encountered the problem with the status bar appearance, in the places I've used this approach we didn't use view-controller based  status bar appearance.  Sorry I can't help you with the final issue.

Answer (score -1):

I've always created a RootController that presents other animated views using UIView containment. I'm not sure that its possible to do the same thing with a UIWindow.

To present an overlay:

**RootController:**

```
- (void)presentOverlayController:(UIViewController *)viewController 
    inNavigationController:(BOOL)inNavigationController
    then:(void (^)())onCompletion
{
    if (!_overlayController)
    {
        _overlayController = inNavigationController ? 
            [self makeNavigationControllerWithRoot:viewController] : viewController;
        [_overlayController willMoveToParentViewController:self];
        [self.view presentOverlayView:_overlayController.view];
        [_overlayController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    }
}
```

**RootView:**

```
- (void)presentOverlayView:(UIView *)view
{
    [CATransaction flush];
    [CATransaction begin];

    _overlayView = view;
    [_overlayView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.height, self.width, self.height + 20)];
    [self addSubview:_overlayView];

    NSString *keyPath = @"position.y";
    NSNumber *toValue = @((self.height / 2) + 10);
    [_overlayView.layer setValue:toValue forKeyPath:keyPath];
    SKBounceAnimation *bounceAnimation = [SKBounceAnimation animationWithKeyPath:keyPath];
    bounceAnimation.fromValue = @(self.height + (self.height / 2));
    bounceAnimation.toValue = toValue;
    bounceAnimation.duration = 1.3f;
    bounceAnimation.numberOfBounces = 4;
    bounceAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
    bounceAnimation.shouldOvershoot = YES;
    bounceAnimation.stiffness = SKBounceAnimationStiffnessHeavy;
    bounceAnimation.fromValue = kCAFillModeForwards;

    [_overlayView.layer addAnimation:bounceAnimation forKey:kOverlayPresent];
    [CATransaction commit];

    [_overlayView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.width, self.height + 20)];
}
```

You can create a category on UIViewController to make it easy to obtain your root VC:

**UIViewController+Root:**

```
- (INFRootController *)rootController
{
    return (INFRootController *) [[[UIApplication sharedApplication].windows objectAtIndex:0] rootViewController];
}
```

**Then just:**

```
[self.rootController presentOverlayController:someController then:^{//doSomething?}];
```

Comment: I typically use UIView containment too of some sort (like making child view controllers, presenting view controllers, etc.), but the problem in this case is that I want the overlay view to be ABOVE the keyboard if it is showing, so I need to do it by creating another UIWindow.

Comment: @user2135004 Ah, I see.